# How to set log level for specific class and package?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Here is my log4j stuff which is in .properties file

```
logging.rootLogger=@DEBUG_LEVEL@, stdout, rollingFile, smtp
##logging.appender.stdout.Threshold=@DEBUG_LEVEL@
logging.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
logging.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
logging.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c [%M:%L] %m%n
```

@DEBUG_LEVEL@ this is set in separate "appenv.bash" file, for different environments it is set differently. In production it is set as ERROR and i want to use INFO for one method in specific class. AS this INFO, DEBUG will not be shown in production environment.

How can I set the log level to INFO for one particular class in one package?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring one logger here, the rootLogger. It is the "parent" of all loggers so if you want a fine-grained configuration you have to declare a more specific logger.

The following line create a logger for all the classes under package com.foo.bar:

```
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN, stdout
```

Your class must instantiate the logger this way:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getCanonicalName());
```

But you can put any string here, for instance:

```
log4j.logger.onlyoneclasswilluseit=WARN, stdout
```

And get it this way :

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("onlyoneclasswilluseit");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but we are using this now in my project. Im just using error level and my colleague is keeping the restriction in splunk tool. SPLUNK is to send the alerts to specific distribution email list. It will pick the error logs from our application log. If i need next time I will with your idea and update here.